# How do I visualize a raster based on its properties using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, visualisation

I am trying to visualize the USDA soil map based on the taxonomy great groups.
On the [info page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/OpenLandMap_SOL_SOL_GRTGROUP_USDA-SOILTAX_C_v01) of the dataset, it seems as if this could be found in the properties. More specifically in grtgroup Class Table: color.

My approach so far did not color it properly.

```
var area =     ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[6.86, 50.75],  [6.86, 50.60],[7.30, 50.60],  [7.30, 50.75]]], null, false);
var soil =ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_GRTGROUP_USDA-SOILTAX_C/v01")
Map.addLayer(soil.clip(area), {}, 'soil');
Map.centerObject(area,11);
print(soil,'soil')

var names = soil.get('visualization_0_name');
print(names);
var band = soil.get('visualization_0_bands');
print(band);
```

I already checked the answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269943/how-do-i-visualize-points-in-a-featurecollection-based-on-feature-properties-usi) and it seems like it is possible to slice out the palette from the properties in the MODIS image.

Is this also possible with the soil dataset and how can I read out the palette values and visualize the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by defining your colors as a dictionary, mapping value to color. Then turn it into an array of colors, where the index is the value, filling non-existing value with some default color. Finally, turn this into a palette string. Remember to set your min and max value too.

```
// *Note*: this code block is all client-side JavaScript - no GEE objects or methods.

var colors = {
  0: 'FFFFFF', 
  1: 'ADFF2D', 
  2: 'ADFF22', 
  4: 'A5FF2F', 
  6: '87FF37',
  // ...
}

var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(colors))
var array = Array.apply(null, Array(maxValue + 1))
  .map(function() { return '000000' })

Object.keys(colors).forEach(function (i) {
  array[i] = colors[i]
})

var palette = array.join(',')
var visParams = {min: 0, max: maxValue, palette: palette}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dfab15f56973e2da30544bc53835edcb

Comment: How did you obtain the color information? Did you just copy it from the data catalog page or how did you get it?

Comment: Yes  - copy and paste from your link